# Without using sort keyword. print numbers in Ascending order in Ruby

Tags: ruby

This is my program, Not getting expected output. This need to print Ascending order.Please help me on this

```
    a=[5,7,6,4,1,3,2,8,9,10]
      temp=0
      i=0
      j=0
    a.each do |i|
    a.each do |j|
        if(i>j)
          temp=i
          i=j
          j=temp 
        end
      end
    end
      puts i
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use `sort`? If so `puts a.sort`

Comment: "Not getting expected output" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. What output do you expect and why, what is the output you are getting and how do the two differ? Also, please take the time to properly format your code. In any halfway decent editor, it should take you 2-3 keypresses do automatically format your code according to Ruby Community Coding Style Guidelines, the fact that you refuse to spend those 100 milliseconds and instead make your code harder to read for the people who invest their own free (or even paid!!!) time to help you for free shows disrespect.

Comment: I apologize i was trying to practice ruby, i tried to print numbers in Ascending order it was not printing. i will try to give more information

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should not compare `i>j`, those are index values of an array.  You should do `a[i]>a[j]`. And also swap values using array and not array_index. If it doesn't bring the output post the error log.

Answer (score 0):

```
#example
a=[3,2,1]
a.each{|x| puts x}
#output:
3
2
1
```

This means that **x** represents values inside **a**, but if you tried to do something like this:

```
a=[3,2,1]
a.each{|x| x = 5}
```

array **a** will not change, to change the values you can do this (using **each_index** method):

```
a.each_index {|x| a[x]=5}
# if you printed the array it will contains three fives.
# Now a = [5,5,5]
# x now will be the indexes 0,1,2,...
```

so my final solution for you problem is:

```
a.each_index do |i|
 a.each_index do |j|
  if(a[i]<a[j])
    temp=a[i]
    a[i]=a[j]
    a[j]=temp 
  end
 end
end
print a
```

Another solution with **for** loop:

```
a=[5,7,6,4,1,3,2,8,9,10]
for i in 0..a.length-1 do
    for j in i..a.length-1 do
        if a[i]>a[j]
            a[i],a[j] = a[j],a[i] #swap
        end
    end
end
print a
```

**Note**:
You had a problem with the condition, You have to use less than instead of greater than if you want to print then in **Ascending Order**, if you used my **for** way the greater than will be used, it is a matter of how your algorithm and your loop works.

Comment: You are welcome, please put this in your mind this algorithm is **O(N*N)** which is a bad thing, I advise you to read more about sorting algorithms and **Complexity** of an algorithm, best wishes.
[sorting](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/) 
if my answer worked for you, could you please accept it, it's up to you to accept it.